# fetch() в Edge 15

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, fetch, microsoft-edge

Всем привет. Пишу сайт с мемасиками, статика хостится на `netlify.com` апишка написана на `wix-code`. Между собой общаются с помощью `fetch()`. Все работает кроме как в Edge/15.

Такой запрос работает и в хроме и в фоксе

```
fetch('https://shoonia.wixsite.com/meme-api/_functions/meme/cc5cdebb-3163-4056-8ec0-e62ba407144e')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(console.log).catch(console.log);
```

А в едже возвращает ошибку

```
{
  description: "Failed to fetch",
  message: "Failed to fetch",
  name: "TypeError",
  number: -2147418113
}
```

Хотя на другие апишки типа `jsonplaceholder.typicode.com` в едже отрабатывает нормально

```
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(console.log);
```

Я в беке не очень понимаю, все по минимум, може кто подскажет. Мои заголовки на ответ на сервере

```
const jsonHeaders = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
    'Cache-Control': 'public, max-age=' + (60 * 15),
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true,
};
```

Comment: в 18 версии не воспроизводится